# Feature Database to Generate IOT Scenarios For Different Ecosystems

Tags: android, database, iot, bigdata

We can access/emulate the features of mobile devices in android development tools. However there are lots of IOT devices with different communication capabilities, features and applications.

Is it possible to find a database that sorts us the software features and physical capabilities of IOT devices on the market. Then matching those features may generate new scenarios for different IOT ecosystems such as home, medical, energy etc. That feature matching process can be driven by developers or automatically.

Briefly, is there a (or is it possible to find out such a) database and generate new scenarios from its entries which are describing device features and physical capabilities. You may know some ongoing projects ...

Comment: I am not aware of a good database. And I'm not sure if a general "IoT device database" even makes sense. Why? Because the range of IoT devices is enormous. But IMHO it would be nice to have a IoT device database for certain IoT markets: industrial gateways, GPS Trackers, Smart Home.

Answer (score 0):

No database known of.  However, several papers that discuss approaches similar to what you're attempting.

[Proactively Extracting IoT Device Capabilities: An Application to Smart Homes](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-030-49669-2_3)

From the article: "we...propose a proactive approach to extract IoT device capabilities from their informational specifications to verify their potential threats, even before a device is installed."

[Internet of Things Device Capabilities, Architectures, Protocols, and Smart Applications in Healthcare Domain: A Review](https://arxiv.org/abs/2204.05921)

From the article: "In this paper, the most common and popular IoT device capabilities, architectures, and protocols are demonstrated in brief to provide a clear overview of the IoT technology to the researchers in this area."

[Internet of Things (IoT) Component Capability Model for Research Testbed - NIST.IR.8316](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/ir/2020/NIST.IR.8316.pdf)

From the article: "This document describes a component capability model for IoT that is being used to develop an IoT research testbed ... It describes several
key terms and core concepts related to IoT and explains how those terms and concepts relate to each other. The model provides a common language that can be used to communicate, specify, review, analyze, and reason about IoT definitions, documents, architectures, components, and systems."

[IoT Device Cybersecurity Capability Core Baseline - NIST.IR.8259A](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/ir/2020/NIST.IR.8259a.pdf)

From the article: "This publication defines an Internet of Things (IoT) device cybersecurity capability core baseline, which is a set of device capabilities generally needed to support common cybersecurity controls that protect an organization’s devices as well as device data, systems, and ecosystems."

Also found an Arduino project attempting something similar.

[IoT Device Capability Discovery with Arduino MKR1000](https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/yanza/iot-device-capability-discovery-with-arduino-mkr1000-05a5af)